# Phrase for "a strong reason for wanting something to happen ..."

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I have a problem with a phrase that can describe the following:

> a strong reason for wanting something to happen because you will get
>   advantage from it.

I need the phrase for a formal essay.

Comment: Could it be "premeditation"?

Comment: A common way to convey this is to say you have a ***vested interest** in something [happening]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have noticed often that you post the most correct answers to questions but in comments. What stops you from posting them as answers instead of comments?

Comment: What is something? Death? Accident? Or somebody's illness? Your question is unclear and what makes you think you can get an answer with that example? Please write an example sentence where the word would be used. The following is the very ***strict*** rule of this community. ***Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered***.I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.

Comment: I am sorry for my ambiguity. English is not my native language. I will think about that next time I ask a question. @Rathony

Comment: @BiscuitBoy 2 reps were given to you for the edit. But, please make sure your edit also covers grammatical mistakes and typos. Please take a look at my edit. I make a mistake in editing, too.:-)

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: See [my answer on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4563/2637). That has a net rating of 0 (4 upvotes and 4 downvotes) - so obviously not everyone endorses my position, but not everyone is *against* it, either. On the other side of the coin, why are *you* apparently so keen to post actual answers which you then quickly delete? At least twice in the past few days I've found that a comment I'd laboriously composed against one of your answers couldn't be posted because you'd deleted the answer *while I was typing*. (We're not working against the clock here, you know! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 1. Thanks for the meta link. 2. The answer (which I had given for this question) is the only answer I have ever deleted in my 10 odd days of ELU usage. I have never deleted my answers before. I am not sure if you can access my [deleted answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/150645) page but the very reason I deleted my answer was your comment, which had the right answer and I didn't want users to get confused seeing my rather inappropriate answer to OP's question

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: Sorry - I must have misremembered a username (well, you've only been here 9 days, and I can't possibly keep track of who *everyone* is! :) Apparently I *can't* view your "recent deleted answers" as a *list* (each of us can only see our own such list). But I *can* see any deleted answers if I'm looking at the page for a specific question.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the expression,

***[ulterior motive](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ulterior-motive):***

> - if you have an ulterior motive for doing something, you do it partly because you think you will get some advantage from doing it.

(macmillandictionary.com)

Comment: Specifically in many cases ***ulterior** motives*.

Comment: Alternatively, the word bias does the job without implying the secrecy.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful expression is,

***[hidden agenda](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hidden+agenda):***

> - an undisclosed plan, especially one with an ulterior motive.

(AHD)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @Chris's answer for a single, concise word.  On the other hand, if you are okay with using an idiom, try

- ***[have a dog in the hunt](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+dog+in+the+hunt)***

> - To have some vested interest in or something to gain by a given situation.
>
>   - *Some people can watch a football game no matter who is playing, but I'm only interested if I've got a dog in the hunt. Many small business owners—whether they know it or not—have a dog in the hunt with this proposed tax bill.*

The origin is from the use of dogs to scent and/or flush game animals, and if a dog you owned was being used, you would desire its success, as this would translate to your success as a hunter.

Comment: Upon [further review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_in_the_game_(phrase)) the call on the field has been overturned.  Thanks.